# Are stream ciphers no longer considered by NIST?

Tags: stream-cipher, standards, nist

While reading [NIST SP 800-90A, "Recommendation for Random Number
Generation Using Deterministic
Random Bit Generators"](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-90A/SP800-90A.pdf), I noted that no stream cipher was included among the various specified solutions.

I also noted that, at least as far as I could tell from the [list of other NIST SP 800 series publications](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/PubsSPs.html), no stream ciphers seem to be currently approved or recommended by NIST.

On the other hand, a set of stream ciphers (MUGI, SNOW 2.0, Rabbit, Decimv2, K2) appear to be currently standardized in [ISO/IEC 18033-4:2011](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_ics/catalogue_detail_ics.htm?csnumber=54532).

So my question is:

- What could be the reasons for NIST to apparently ignore stream ciphers?
- Is it due to the past failure of any stream ciphers to pass the [NESSIE](https://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/nessie/) project validation, or is it simply due to reduced interest in dedicated stream ciphers, as compared to stream cipher constructions based on block ciphers (CTR / OFB mode)?

Comment: look estream project http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/

Comment: thanks for  estream derived portfolio while i only mentionned stream ciphers standardized by ISO. it is strange for me that no stream cipher appears approved by nist for PRG or for encryption

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know, but block-cipher based modes of operation have seen a lot more scrutiny.  AES in CTR mode has been vetted much more thoroughly than any of those stream ciphers you mention.  Moreover, those stream ciphers do not offer compelling benefits over AES-CTR mode.  Therefore, it seems to me it would be entirely reasonable to focus on block-cipher based modes of operation.

Comment: thanks for answer & post update with missed URL links. I think you're right and nist might not consider a major interest for stream ciphers. this is not a minor concern according to nist rôle.

Comment: Why the Alternating Step Generator is not used more is beyond me, there has been no public cryptanalysis(break) of this generator since it was published in 1987,26 years ago, that is long time to stand up to public scrutiny. It may be un-crackable as long as the key length is large enough, it is an amazingly simple algorithm.